# How can I call a translation with the translation key being a variable?

Tags: ruby, iteration, translation

I would like to display a translation where the current item in an iteration is the translation key.

In my model I have :

```
def self.topics                                                                                                                   
    [ "topic_birds", "topic_trees"  ]
end
```

In my view :

```
Book.topics.each do |topic|
    ...
    <p><%= t(topic) %></p>
    ...
end
```

And in my YML file

```
topic_birds: 'Birds'
topic_trees: 'Trees'
```

Instead of returning :

```
Birds
Trees
```

My code returns :

```
Topic Birds
Topic Trees
```

So it seems the translation function does not accept or interpret the variable `topic` properly in my `each` statement. Instead it returns a formatted version of the key (uppercase first letter and spaces) and not the translation from the YML file.

Comment: What's not working?
The yml should (by convention) be named by language, such as `en.yml`, and the file should be fully nested within the language key. `en:`, and everything nested within that key/object. (So the fully qualified translation key in YML is `en.topic_birds`, and the call is `t('topic_birds')`, while `I18n.locale = :en`

Comment: @wyattisimo beat me to it :). He answered exactly, what I was going to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the specified key cannot be found in your language yml file, the default behavior of Rails translation helper is to use the specified key as the value. This appears to be what you are experiencing.

If you inspect the HTML output of your view, you will see the "translated" value is wrapped in an element with a special `translation_missing` class and title, e.g.:

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.topic_birds">Topic Birds</span>
```

---

**Tip:** You can cause missing translations to raise an error by setting `ActionView::Base.raise_on_missing_translations = true`.

---

Based on the information you provided, I'm guessing the language yml file is structured properly, so the likely issue is that the `topic_birds` and `topic_trees` keys are defined in a different locale than what is set in the app.

For example, if you have an en.yml file that looks like this:

```
en:
  topic_birds: 'Birds'
  topic_trees: 'Trees'
```

...but the app's locale is set to `de`, then you will experience the issue you're describing.

You can set the locale with `I18n.locale = :en`.

Comment: You put me on the right track, there was a typo on the keys in the language file, ugh.